# Why does a type of T[keyof T] prevent covariance in an interface

Tags: typescript, covariance

I am trying to make a type covariant so that `Type<Cat>` can be treated as a `Type<Animal>` for example (like a list of Cats is a list of Animals). But for some reason, using the type `T[keyof T]` in a method in the Type interface seems to prevent that.

```js
type Animal = {
    legs: boolean;
}

type Dog = Animal & {
    golden: boolean;
}

//This exhibits covariance
interface Comparer<T> {
    compare(a: T, b: T): number;
}

//this is valid
declare let animalComparer: CovariantComparer<Animal>;
declare let dogComparer: CovariantComparer<Dog>;

animalComparer = dogComparer;
dogComparer = animalComparer;  

//This does not
interface NonCovariantComparer<T> {
    compare(a: T, b: T[keyof T]): number;
}

declare let animalComparer2: NonCovariantComparer<Animal>;
declare let dogComparer2: NonCovariantComparer<Dog>;

animalComparer2 = dogComparer2; //typeerror
dogComparer2 = animalComparer2; //typeerror
```

Is there a way to make that work? Or if not, why is it impossible and is there a good pattern to get around this issue? Thanks!

Note: I'm working off of the assumption that [making the object a method will make it bivariant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#note)

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDeAoKQqNCAcwGcAuKAIwHs6SU4BuPAXzz1EigBE6pLLESoMAMlwEipRgBMIcavUYRmbTngRxgEAE4AzFAGNoAYToA3FHoTNgFpGBv6APABUAfFKJRjdJxcAChRqdwAaWjCASmo4AFckGn0NLgVjNBdiCGAoZmR0R2c9fWoLa1t7Ipc9V3gCtE82dMyS7Ny5QWqSvTKrGzsdbrcBUiaufLFhvWFO0mnmroDi-WFJwuWalkIubV1DE2gAOTo4coGqzZ6Pb3xff0CSkLDImjCAbQBrCBA6Ayh3ABdWJQBJJFIcNIQDJZEi5dZoaYAJmoJzO-UqQyubnqYnGLVhOSgc2RqNO50xDmxtVG4zwCORsyWj30SMW82pSLWog2LL0bKAA)

Comment: Are your last two lines actually supposed to be `animalComparer2 = dogComparer2;
dogComparer2 = animalComparer2;`? If you change it, the TypeScript error is quite clear what it doesn't like about the assignment: `Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'Dog'. Property 'golden' is missing in type 'Animal' but required in type '{ golden: boolean; }'.`

Comment: oh no oops but it's still an error. i will fix

Comment: Yes but why is typescript trying to do that? I'm basically trying to make a type like List (where a List of dogs is a list of animals), but typescript seems to disallow that when I add a method like this.

Comment: Your "covariant" example `Comparer<T>` is actually contravariant in `T`.

Comment: I thought it didn't do that if you made `compare` a method rather than a property. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a generic type `U extends T` on the `compare()` method of the interface seems to resolve the errors:

```
type Animal = {
    legs: boolean;
}

type Dog = Animal & {
    golden: boolean;
}

interface CovariantComparer<T> {
    compare<U extends T>(a: T, b: U[keyof T]): number;
}

declare let animalComparer: CovariantComparer<Animal>;
declare let dogComparer: CovariantComparer<Dog>;

animalComparer = dogComparer;
dogComparer = animalComparer;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDeAoKQqNCAcwGcAuKAIwHs6SU4BuPAXzz1EigBE6pLLESoMAMlwEipRgBMIcavUYRmbTngRxgEAE4AzFAGNoAYToA3FHoTNgFpGBv6APABUAfFKJRjdJxdXAFUoCAAPXTg5cigvAAoUancAGlpqYIBtAGsIEDoDOIBdAEpqOABXJBp9DS4FYzQXYghgKGZkdEdnPX1qC2tbe26XPVd4TrRPNgam3pa2uUER3r1+qxs7HRW3AVJprg6xHb1hJdITmeWAnv1hI66b0ZYgA)

Comment: That does seem to work! Thanks! Though I don't really get why.